# What does this socket error mean?

Tags: html, http, sockets

First of all thanks to everyone that answers questions on here. I have used this forum as a java bible. This is a homework problem and here is the assignment:

> Write a program in Java that uses sockets to connect to a web server on port 80, requests a web page using GET of the HTTP protocol, and displays the resulting HTML

Not sure if I am doing this right or not.  I have a very limited understanding of java.  Most of this is from tutorials I have been going through. Any website links would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.net.Socket to Socket
The method getInputStream() is undefined for the type Socket
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class Server
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server SERVER = new Server();
        SERVER.run();
    }

    public void run() throws Exception
    {
        ServerSocket one = new ServerSocket(80);

        //these are the two lines of code it is warning about

        Socket myskt = one.accept();
        InputStreamReader IR = new InputStreamReader(myskt.getInputStream());

        //end of warnings

        BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(IR);

        String message = BR.readLine();
        System.out.println(message);

        if (message != null)
        {
            PrintStream PS = new PrintStream(System.out);
            PS.println("Message Received");
        }

        URL website = new URL("www.dogs.com");
        URLConnection yc = website.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in .readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);

        one.close();
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Comment: First: you're asked to write a *client*, no need for server sockets then.  Second, *if* you're allowed to use the `URL` class getting a page from a webserver is pretty trivial.  If not I assume you're supposed to handle the whole client socket thing yourself, and write a basic http client on top of that (but a basic http client is trivial, really).  So first of all get rid of the first part of your program and then make sure using URL is permitted in this assignment.

Comment: I did compete the assignment using URL and it was very easy.  I think he is wanting us to use the sockets, however. So googling http client should put me on the right track?

Comment: The error messages indicate you're having problems with variable type declarations. Get that right before worrying about the HTTP client protocol.

Comment: It looks as though there is *another* Socket type floating about: "cannot convert from *java.net.Socket* to *Socket*" - so where/what is the conflicting type? (Does the current project define its own Socket class by chance?)

Comment: If you are allowed to, look at using the `HttpURLConnection` class instead of implementing the HTTP protocol manually. Otherwise, use the `Socket` class instead of the `ServerSocket` class, but you will have to send an actual HTTP command yourself, you can't just open the connection and start reading, since you haven't told the server what to send yet. If you use `URL` instead of `Socket`, then you have to specify the complete HTTP url, ie: `http://www.dogs.com`.

Comment: @dancer_rcd indeed.  And although pst is right, it's in the server side of things so maybe don't waste too much time on that part.  Wrt the client side of sockets: [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that our code is not well-formed - you have a compilation error. My guess is that you have a class `Socket` in the same package as the class you're compiling, or a left-over class file (Socket.class) on the classpath. When the compiler runs, it uses the package local version of Socket, which is not the same type as `java.net.Socket` - hence the exception.

To resolve thisuse the fully qualified name java.net.Socket when declaring `myskt`